# вызов метода фрагмента в активти

Tags: javascript, java, android

Есть фрагмент `TwoFragment` ,  в нем есть метод

```
WebView mWebView;

public void reloadWebView() {
  mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload(true)");
}
```

Пытаюсь в `MainActivity` использовать этот метод следющим образом:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
```

Не срабатывает,  почему?

Comment: Вы получили ссылку на фрагмент но сам метод-то не вызвали...

Comment: и как его вызвать я уже устал))

Comment: `fragment.reloadWebView();` же...

Comment: не несовсем эт не сработает так как я пытался воссоздать то что есть .я уже нашел способ  другой прилось заменить адаптер

Comment: сделал глобальный адаптер и через фрагмент сразу обратился так как

Comment: все фрагменты уже были заданы как дочение в main activity и через него поставил прямой доступ если инетерсно могу опубликовать

Comment: Опубликуйте - кому-то может это помочь в будущем)